# Issue in deployment of SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am getting the below error while deploying the SSIS package on the server

> Error Message:
>       Load Account:Error: System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManager100.AcquireConnection(Object pTransaction)
>      at PW.TaskFactory.BasePipelineComponent.GetConnectionFromConnectionManager(Object tx, ConnectionManager manager, Boolean checkSqlVersion)
>      at PW.TaskFactory.BasePipelineComponent.GetConnection(Object tx, String connectionNameProperty, Boolean checkSqlVersion)
>      at PW.TaskFactory.UpsertDestinationTask.UpsertDestination.AcquireConnections(Object transaction)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostAcquireConnections(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Object transaction)

Is there any particular deployment setting which is giving this error?

Comment: Hi Vishal, were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are running Pragmatic Works' Task Factory component "Upsert Destination" in the package, and it is having a problem creating a connection. There are a couple questions I have.

- Do you have a licensed copy of Task Factory on the server that you are trying to deploy too?
- Did you assign an ADO .NET connection manager properly in the Upsert Destination when you created the package?

If you are not sure, or are still having problems, I would reach out to Pragmatic Works technical support for help with the issue at support@pragmaticworks.com.

Comment: Thanks Josh for replying.

Comment: Thanks, we have a licensed copy of Task Factory on the server we are trying to deploy. I think the setting of ADO .NET connection manager in the Upsert Destination is also correct also we have set the ADO,NET connection at the project level.

Comment: I would reach out to PW support then. There are a multitude of issues that you could be having right now. Haley and the team will be happy to help you.